# OpenGL ES set Texture matrix for different Texturing units

Tags: opengl-es, matrix, multitexturing

with

```
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
..some matrix operations...
```

i can change the current texture transformation matrix. However - it seems it affects not all texture units (i'm using multitexturing)

how can i change the texture matrix for different texture units?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using glActiveTexture to select the appropriate texture matrix stack. This works for OpenGL, and I assume that it should also work for OpenGL ES.